# What is the difference between boost's "windows_shared_memory" and boost's "managed_windows_shared_memory"?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

Boost provides several types of shared memory. Amongst them, `windows_shared_memory` uses Windows' own underlying shared memory capabilities and is therefore platform specific and has some specificities compared to other shared memories (POSIX compatible ones).

It is described [here in the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory.windows_shared_memory).

However, in [this other documentation page](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_shared_memory.windows_managed_memory_common_shm), the `managed_windows_shared_memory` is described. Neither mentions the other one's existence.

What is the difference between these two shared memory implementations ?

It looks to me that they both have the same behaviour according to the documentation. Are they just the same mechanism that just displays two different interfaces to use them ?

The includes containing the two implementations :

```
// The first implementation has to be included here
#include <boost/interprocess/windows_shared_memory.hpp>

// The second implantation has to be included here
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_windows_shared_memory.hpp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "managed" in boost distinguishes several class interface families, not just **windows** shared memory. The non-"managed" versions are more direct and minimal, supplying just what is needed for low-level operation. The "managed" versions are typically built atop the non-"managed", but also include more boost template magic to give a safer, higher-level interface. Generally prefer "managed" versions because they do more for you.